# runtime error after running bubble sort

Tags: c, arrays, runtime-error, bubble-sort

I'm trying to write a program that bubble sorts an array, but every time I run it this error pops up: `runtime error: index 4 out of bounds for type 'int [e]'`

what is the issue here?

```
int main(void) {
    printf("How many elements are there in the array?: ");
    int e = get_int();

    int array[e];

    for (int i = 0; i < e; i++) {
        printf("Insert element #%i: ", i + 1);
        array[i] = get_int();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < e - 1; e++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < e - i - 1; j++) {
            if (array[j] > array[j + 1]) {
                int swap = array[j];
                array[j] = array[j + 1];
                array[j + 1] = swap;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Seriously? you find that error message confusing?

Comment: Kindly show your research / debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: Please read how to produce a [mcve] - you need to provide all the inputs and the expected outputs too!

Comment: Looks like in `i ==0`, ` if(array[j] > array[j + 1])`, the last iteration would cause issues....check with a pen and paper.

Comment: your runtime is very nice. Others would go "runtime error, code 0x232532464 - go to hell"...

Answer (score 2):

You mistyped the `for` loop increment part: `for (int i = 0; i < e - 1; e++)` should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < e - 1; i++)
```

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("How many elements are there in the array?: ");
    int e = get_int();

    for (int i = 0; i < e; i++) {
        printf("Insert element #%i: ", i + 1);
        array[i] = get_int();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < e - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < e - i - 1; j++) {
            if (array[j] > array[j + 1]) {
                int swap = array[j];
                array[j] = array[j + 1];
                array[j + 1] = swap;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("{ ");
    for (int i = 0; i < e; i++) {
        printf("%d, ", array[i]);
    }
    printf("}\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: I guess I would have used `n` instead of `e`.

Comment: I fixed the for loop, but the output of the program is messed up. if the array is { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1} it outputs 4, 2, 3, 4. why?

Comment: @chqrlie now go and deserve your 10 rep :)

Comment: @AshleyMoe your loop is messed up. Use i and j and go up to n. Start from i+1 for the inner loop and _use_ both indices instead of the stupid +1

Comment: @AshleyMoe: you must have mistyped the fix or the output loop, I get the correct result.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the error noted by chqrlie, don't overcomplicate a bubble sort (and it's buggy, it's only considering contiguous indices). Write that simply (note that the inner loop is optimized to avoid processing the "lower triangle" items twice):

```
for (int i = 0; i < e; i++) {
    for (int j = i+1; j < e; j++) {
        if (array[j] > array[i]) {
            int swap = array[j];
            array[j] = array[i];
            array[i] = swap;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: you deserve yours too, but the above code implements a slightly different sorting algorithm: a mix of selection and bubble sort.  Bubble sort only swaps adjacent elements.  Ashley's version bubbles the elements to the end of the array and she does not process the lower triangle either, just a different one. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Comment: @chqrlie good to know (now I understand why OP code is so complex). I know I'll never reinvent a better sort than the researchers did or will do, so I try to keep it simple: bubble sort or _call some library_ :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: re-implementing and tuning sorting algorithms is a very interesting and humbling experience. Try `qsort` or radixsort for breakfast ;-)